# how to set vimrc tags to use shell environment variables

Tags: shell, vim, vi

I tried but failed and need an expert help. In a .vimrc I have the following:

`set tags=/sandbox/myNameIsSam/tags`

This works just fine. Inside gvim, I can load the tags file and everything is awesome. However, I would like for each user to have their own project tags file. How and why is not important here. The below setting doesn't seem to do what I need. Can someone help?

```
let projectTagFile='/sandbox/'.$USERNAME.'/tags'
set tags=projectTagFile
```

Answer (score 5):

you should get username  by `$USER` not `$USERNAME`

What is important is that in this particular case, you cannot use `set` to set this option because it only allows you to set it to a single literal value. However, with `let`, you can use Vimscript to obtain the value using a function, for example, or in your case, through concatenation (read more about about options [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/19.html)). Try this instead:

```
let &tags='/sandbox/'.$USER.'/tags'
```

To check if the `tags` was set correctly, you could execute:

```
:set tags?
```

Or, for the fully-qualified path:

```
:echo &tags
```

Comment: `USERNAME` is the name of that particular environment variable on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I've always done something like

```
let tagfile = '/sandbox/' . $USERNAME . '/tags'
execute 'set tags=' . tagfile
```

but I now like @Kent's solution better.  Doing it like that had never crossed my mind.